# Woking on a socket file transfer with lz4 compression support using golang

Tags: go

This package ["github.com/pierrec/lz4"](https://github.com/pierrec/lz4)

When uncompress, use `lz4.NewReader(reader)`, the *reader* is `bufio.Reader(net.Conn)`

Problem is: I need to know the `bufio.Reader(net.Conn)` Read length of byte in order to calculate total size and finish the transition properly, but `lz4.NewReader(reader)` only give me the uncompressed size

Is there any way like some proxy like object thing to get `n` of `bufio.Reader(net.Conn)`.Read and let `lz4.NewReader(bufio.Reader(net.Conn)).Read` do it thing?

Comment: you already have the proxy idea, it is not difficult to implement a io.Reader proxy, wrapping the Read() method.

Comment: my experience with golang is not much，can't figure out how to do it，need an example